# I want to set up a rotation for my 6 team members to meet for lunch each month

Tags: rotations

I have a team of $6$ that will meet in pairs of $2$ each month ($3$ groups each month) throughout the year. How do I set up a rotation to distribute?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Looks like a "tournament" issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this: imagine them sitting at a dining table, with 3 chairs on each side. The people sitting facing each other are the pairs you form for your first round of meetings. Now fix one person in their seat. After each round, the other 5 rotate one position to the right, skipping over the person fixed to their seat.

This gives you all possible pairs precisely once. (This works for any even number of people, not just 6.)